# Remote Mercurial without installing Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I have a server with ssh, that I want to use as a central repo. However I can not install mercurial on it. Therefore how can clients push to the server over ssh without having mercurial installed on the server.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to install mercurial on that server. if you can mount it then you can create a regular repository by providing the path to "hg init" for creating a repository on this remote server.

Another way is sshfs. This is a filesystem client based on the SSH File Transfer Protocol.

- http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

So using this you could do

```
sshfs hostname: mountpoint # mounts the file system
hg init mountpoint # do your mercurial operation
fusermount -u mountpoint # unmounts the file system
```

I have not done this but you could give a try.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that you can *probably* install mercurial on the server even if you think you can't.  If you have a system with a similar architecture you can `make local` to install mercurial right in its own distribution directory and then just `scp` that up to the server.

The only difference in this case is that if you can't get the resulting you@there:mercurialCopiedIn/hg into the `$PATH` then you'll need to use the `--remotecmd` argument on your pushes and pulls to say what binary to use.

Answer (score 1):

If the local system can mount the remote repository using `sshfs` then that would work.  Otherwise you're out of luck.  :-(